# Why does CGBlendMode.color work correctly in simulator but fail on device?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgcontext, cashapelayer

I'm using `CAShapeLayer`'s `render(in:)` with blend mode set to `CGBlendMode.color` to tint an image drawn to the current CGContext. It works perfectly in the simulator, but not on the device.

[image: Simulated iPhone 7 Plus]
[image: Actual iPhone 7 Plus]

Screenshot on the left is a simulated iPhone 7 Plus, on the right is the actual device running iOS 10.2. First the black square is drawn, then the red circle, then the CGBlendMode is set to `color` and the blue circle is drawn.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgblendmode) for `CGBlendMode.color` says:

> Uses the luminance values of the background with the hue and
>   saturation values of the source image.

So where the blue circle overlaps the black background, it should use luminance of zero and draw black.

Why does this work correctly in the simulator but not on the real device? And more importantly, how can I get this type of blend to work on the device?

To reproduce, create a new project in Xcode 8.2.1 with the "Single View Application" template and replace `ViewController.swift` with:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let blendModeTestView = BlendModeTest(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 250))
        view.addSubview(blendModeTestView)
    }
}

class BlendModeTest: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        // black background
        let backgroundPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        let backgroundShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        backgroundShapeLayer.path = backgroundPath.cgPath
        backgroundShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        backgroundShapeLayer.render(in: context)

        // red circle
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.height/2),
                                      radius: rect.size.width/4,
                                      startAngle: CGFloat(0),
                                      endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.render(in: context)

        // blue circle (with .color blend mode)
        let colorFillPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero,
                                         radius: rect.size.width * 0.8,
                                         startAngle: CGFloat(0),
                                         endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2),
                                         clockwise: true)
        let colorFillShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        colorFillShapeLayer.path = colorFillPath.cgPath
        colorFillShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        context.setBlendMode(.color)
        colorFillShapeLayer.render(in: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have run your code on an iPhone 6s and it showed the same result as in your left image.

Comment: @MartinR Well that's interesting. I don't have a 6s handy to test but my 7 Plus generated the screenshot on the right. There isn't any setting on the device that could cause this, is there?

Comment: If you just want a mask you can do that with your shapes. Also if you just want to avoid the bug you can draw to a UIImage instead of a UIView.

Comment: @GregRobertson My actual application involves coloring a photo, so a shape mask wouldn't work. But drawing to a UIImage works and this bug does not appear. Thanks!